# Formal Space and Rational Homotopy Theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Please give me the proof that for a formal space Massey triple products vanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very special case of a very general result.  A quasi-isomorphism of DGAs identifies Massey products (not just triple products but matrix Massey products of all sizes). See for example Theorem 1.5 of ``Matric Massey products'', http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/8.pdf.  But of course you must interpret your statement modulo indeterminacy.

Comment: Sir,what do you mean by indeterminacy?

Comment: A Massey product is not an element but a set of elements.  Look at the definition of a triple product and think about adding a cycle to the choice of chains with the required products of cycles as their boundaries. But it would be better to look up the definitions before asking questions.